# Trouble setting up Hamachi Gateway in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, vpn, ubuntu-16.04, gateway, hamachi

I've been trying to setup a Hamachi Gateway network using a linux VM running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as the gateway computer for the office network I want remote access too. Right now, I have created the network, the VM, and installed Hamachi on my windows laptop as a client to access the remote network. However, once I configure the Linux box to be the gateway for the network from the Hamachi webpage, my VM looses all connectivity to outside networks (I can still ping and SSH into it from the office network but it can't see other computers on the office network or the internet). To give more details. I wrote down the steo-by-step instructions I followed to setup everything along with the outputs I'm seeing:

**Setting up the VM**

- Created using VirtualBox with the latest Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server Image
- Network set to Bridge Mode with Promiscuous mode set to "Allow All"
- Configured with Static IP address of 10.0.0.5/8, default Gateway of 10.0.0.1 and dns servers of 10.0.0.1 and 1.1.1.1
- SSH Server installed (all following setup done through PuTTY SSH terminal)

After setting up the VM, I verified I can reach the internet and all private IP addresses on the office LAN.

**Hamachi Account Setup**

- Gateway Network created under account (OfficeLAN)
- 1 Windows client joined to gateway network
- Network configured with password and join requests must be approved

**Steps to install and configure Hamachi on Linux VM**

1. Install Hamachi packages

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.203-1_amd64.deb
   sudo hamachi login
   sudo hamachi attach  my-email@gmail.com
   ```
2. Go to website and approve account activation (account page > My Networks > Look for link that says "You have 1 pending join request")
3. Attach client to Hamachi network

   `sudo hamachi do-join 441-xxx-xxx` (network numbers omitted for privacy)
4. Then go to to account page > My Networks > OfficeLAN (edit) > Join Requests > Approve VPN for access to network
5. From the My Networks page, goto Edit (for the network) > Add/Remove Computers and select vpn as the gateway computer. Save settings.
6. Noted that the VPN computer can no longer ping any clients on the LAN and shows up as offline from my windows Hamachi client

Again, after following the above steps. I can ping the VM and SSH into it, but it can't ping any computers on the OfficeLAN or the Internet. So I typed in the following command to check the Hamachi status:

`sudo Hamachi`

And got the following:

```
pid        : 21940
status     : logged in
client id  : 253-xxx-xxx (omitted)
address    : 25.44.180.28    2620:9b::192c:b41c
nickname   : vpn
lmi account: my-email@gmail.com
```

Typing in the command:

`sudo Hamachi list`

Gives the following:

```
* [441-xxx-xxx]OfficeLAN  capacity: 2/5,   [10.0.0.5/8]  subscription type: Free, owner: my-email@gmail.com
     * 253-xxx-xxx   MY-WINDOWS-LAPTOP                                    alias: not set                                                       via server  TCP
```

So it seems like it was at least communicating with the Hamachi account before the network died, but I have no network access through it as a Gateway. Is there something else I’m missing here? Here’s an updated output from the ifconfig command:

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:c0:54:92
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec0:5492/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd5b:3582:fdc:0:a00:27ff:fec0:5492/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1856182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1736840175 (1.7 GB)  TX bytes:1188377 (1.1 MB)

ham0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7a:79:00:00:00:00
          inet addr:25.44.180.28  Bcast:25.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: 2620:9b::192c:b41c/96 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::7879:ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1324 (1.3 KB)

ham1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:c3:2c:b4:1c
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:c3ff:fe2c:b41c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
          RX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3120 (3.1 KB)  TX bytes:1085628 (1.0 MB)

ham-br0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:c3:2c:b4:1c
          inet addr:10.0.0.5  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec0:5492/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
          RX packets:3677 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:684 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1083089 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:77338 (77.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
         inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:22492 (22.4 KB)  TX bytes:22492 (22.4 KB)
```

Also, here’s a printout of the ip routing table (from executing netstat -rn)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ham-br0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 ham-br0
25.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 ham0
```

and lastly, here's the output of running the `ip route` command:

```
10.0.0.0/8 dev ham-br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.5
25.0.0.0/8 dev ham0  proto kernel  scope link  src 25.44.180.28
```

Pinging the windows Hamachi client fails also. I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking at with the above outputs, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been pulling my hair out over this for the past few days with no solution so far.